# passing coordinates from mysql to js via php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

So, i've a working js script that calls a php script that executes a mysql query.
The bad part is when i try to pass the coordinates back to the js script because they are unformatted.
Example:
the array i would like to have is {xx.xxxxxxx, yy.yyyyyyy...}
instead i get {xx.xxxxxxxyy.yyyyyyy and so on}.
here is the php query code UPDATED:

```
<?php 
include('config.php'); //richiama lo script per la connessione al database

$org_name=$_POST['valor']; //riceve il nome dell'organizzazione terroristica desiderata

$return = array();
$query=mysql_query("SELECT longitude, latitude FROM gtdb WHERE `gname` LIKE '$org_name%' and longitude!=''"); //esegue una query al database
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)&&$row2=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $return[] = array($row['longitude'], $row2['latitude']);
}
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

here is the javascript code that triggers the query, when it gets back the datas from the query calls the dataadder function (see the next section of js code):

```
var Datas = [new google.maps.LatLng(32.7603282, 46.343451)];
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#gnome').change(function() {
    var inpval=$(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'php/query.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {valor : inpval},
        success: function(data) {
            while(Datas.length > 0) {
               Datas.pop();
            }
            alert(data);
            Datas = dataadder(data);
            initialize(); //reinitialize gmap with the new datas
                            alert(Datas);
        }
    });
});
});
```

dataadder code

```
function dataadder(array){
var arr2 = [];
var i=0;
var j=1;
while(j<=array.length){
    arr2.push("new google.maps.LatLng("+array[i]+")");
    i+=2;
    j+=2;
}
alert(arr2);
return(arr2);
}
```

Any help?

Comment: **Do not format json yourself**. Generate an array and convert it to json using built-in methods.

Comment: Also `content-type: application/json` in the output of your script is likely to be needed

Answer (score 0):

You should probably try with `json_encode`, something like this :

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT longitude, latitude FROM gtdb WHERE `gname` LIKE '$org_name%' and longitude!=''"); //esegue una query al database
$return = array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $return[] = array($row['longitude'], $row['latitude']);
    //or $return[] = ''. $row['longitude'] . '.' . $row['latitude'];
    //if you want one 'xxx.yyy' string per row of the output
}
echo json_encode($return);
```

this will output something like `[['xxx','yyyy'], ['xxx','yyyy']]`. you then need to call that php with `$.getJSON(...)` instead of $.ajax(). also you'll have to adapt dataadder accordingly.

and as said in comments, add application/json as your content-type

Comment: Tried that and all longitudes became "null" O.o
and how do i add the content-type?

Comment: header('Content-type: application/json');

Comment: also, why are you using fetch-array and fetch-assoc for row 1 and 2?

Comment: i did that in first place, also tried to change mysql_fetch_array in mysql_fetch_assoc but still nothing, i will update the code in the question

Comment: add `dataType: "json"` in your AJAX call if you don't take his advice with the `$.getJSON()` and you should be good to go.  If it isn't coming back formatted, don't forget to decode it back to JSON when it's returned from the server - `var newData = JSON.parse(data);` will do the trick in Javascript.

Comment: after that i get a null value from the php script... i'll update the code in the question with the changes you suggested, just in case i did something wrong.

Comment: @Boris: What should i use instead of fetch-array and fetch-assoc?

Comment: well it's just that doing it like that, you are gerring your longitude and lattitude from two different rows of your query. also, if you have only one row, it will never be taken... I'll edit the code again

Comment: please try this while loop one and give us the output

Comment: By now i'm getting a null result because of the php ajax call, seems like it can't parse json in the first js code

Comment: can we maybe access query.php to see the output?

Comment: ok, problem fixed, updated files in the link i gave you, and edited the code above.
the last error i get is in the dataadder function, i wont the output:"new google.maps.LatLng(36.3064,33.5111)"
but i get that "new google.maps.LatLng(36.3064,33.5111,37.159272,36.215578)" instead, i have too much coordinates .-.

Comment: Fixed, and code updated, but i still cannot update the map :(

Comment: I think that will have to be a new question. Glad you got at least a bit forward :)